# Probability of heights question, don't completely understand the solution

Tags: probability

I would like to know how the answer came about to this question.

```
Assume the heights of woman in a certain country are normally 
distributed with parameters u = 63 inches and k = 3 inches. If a woman 
from this country is selected at random, what is the probability that 
she will be taller than 68 inches?






p(x > 68)

  step 1: p(x-u/k) =  68-63/3 = 1.67

  step 2: .5 - p(0 < z < 1.67) = .5 - .4525 = .0475
```

I understand step 1 but in step 2, where did the `.5` come from and where did the `.4525` come from?

Comment: I think I just figured out what your problem is, after submitting an answer and editing it later.  The question says "normally distributed"  meaning it's a gaussian distribution AKA bell-shaped curve. There's a wealth of information online that will explain what the question really means and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

From a table or from a calculator. Using my favorite table, I find that .9525 of the population is less than 1.67 standard deviations from the mean, so .0475 is 1.67 std dev greater.

The values of the normal distribution are like trig functions in practice. There are ways to calculate them but no one would. The person posing the question used a table to get .4525 (a different table from mine, which is why the looked-up value was less and had to be subtracted from 0.5, rather than 1.) I know the value in the answer came from a table because it's the value for 1.67 std dev. Using a calculator, or spreadsheet, or whatever would have given 0.952209648, the value for 1 + 2/3.

Comment: @dbx how's that a +1?  No info is provided on how to do compute this on the calculator nor table.  This should be a -5 and not an acceptable answer.

Comment: Because the author has a favorite table! Do you have a favorite table?

Comment: @dbx Well, I guess it's safe to assume that this community contains a bunch of immature people.  I couldn't even get an explanation to a question.  Thanks for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

One has $X \sim \mathcal{N}(63,9)$. Then $$P(X>68) = 1 - P(X<68) = 1 - \phi(\frac{68-63}{3}) = 1 - \phi(1.67) = 1 - 0.9525 = 0.0475.$$

Comment: Wait, what does ϕ equal to?  How did 1.67 magically turn into .9525?